# Qt How can add an item to scene with an offset?

Tags: c++, qt, trigonometry

I add a QGraphicsItem(bullet) to the base of a line. The advance method moves the item through the item making it seem as if it comes from the tip of line. After adding collision this doesn't work. Is there a way to add an offset to the setPos(x,y) value to make it appear at the tip of the line instead of the base.

Also the line rotates in a 360 degree angle so it needs to translate to where ever the line is pointing.

```
//function that adds item to base of line created

    qreal dirx = m_FireTarget1.x()+140;
    qreal diry = m_FireTarget1.y()-195;


    qreal length = sqrt(dirx*dirx+diry*diry);
    if (length!=0)
    {
        // normalized direction vector
        qreal invLength= 1.0/length;
        dirx *= invLength;
        diry *= invLength;

        // creating an angle perturbation of +/- 3°
        qreal alphaPerturbation = static_cast<qreal>(qrand()%6-3) * M_PI / 180.0;
        qreal xPerturbation = cos(alphaPerturbation);
        qreal yPerturbation = sin(alphaPerturbation);

        dirx = dirx*xPerturbation - diry*yPerturbation;

        diry = diry*xPerturbation + dirx*yPerturbation;

        GraphicsCircle * circle = new GraphicsCircle(dirx, diry, -140, 195);
        addItem(circle);
```

The -140, 195 is the base of where line is created. Seems like I already did what you're saying to do I believe.

Comment: There are various things I don't understand from your code.
I thought you said you were trying to place the bullet on the opposite end of the line but, from your code, it looks like you are only trying to add a small random displacement. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: `GraphicsCircle * circle = new GraphicsCircle(dirx, diry, -140, 195);` adds a circle at (-140, 195) scene coordinates. That position is the base of a lineitem `cannon = new QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x1 + 50, y1);`. That line rotates at the vertex (-140, 195) in a 360 degree angle. What I was trying to figure out is to position each GraphicsCirle out in front of the line where the lineitems moves in that 360 degree angle. The line is associated with mousemoveevent so it can point to where ever the mouse is positioned in the scene.

Comment: Edited again. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your line has a certain `degreeAngle` and you want to move the bullet to a certain `distance` in that direction, you'll have to do:

```
// cos and sin functions get radians angle as argument so you must convert it
radiansAngle = degreeAngle * PI / 180;
offsetX = distance * cos(radiansAngle);
offsetY = distance * sin(radiansAngle);
```

In your case this translate to:

```
qreal radiansAngle = line.angle() * M_PI / 180;
qreal offsetX = line.length() * cos(radiansAngle);
qreal offsetY = line.length() * sin(radiansAngle);
```

So your new position is the old one plus the offset:

```
qreal newX = -140 + offsetX;
qreal newY =  195 + offsetY;
```

And then I'm sorry but I can't understand how you pass arguments to the `GraphicsCircle` constructor but if `GraphicsCircle * circle = new GraphicsCircle(dirx, diry, -140, 195);` place the circle to the coordinates (-140,195), then you should use...

```
GraphicsCircle * circle = new GraphicsCircle(dirx, diry, newX, newY);
addItem(circle);
```

...to place it to the new coordinates.

Comment: The angle is in `cannonarm->setRotation(360 - line.angle());` in a different function. The offset is just placing the setPos in a different location and not certain `distance` from the origin setPos that is set. Any idea why?

Comment: From your code it seems like you have your angle expressed in degree.
I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Supplied code for you so you can see exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: I tried that but I'm going to have to just figure something else out. The offset is way off from the line. But it has to do with function `mousemoveevent` and creation of `QLineF arm(cannonP1->pos(), e->scenePos());`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but I really can't understand what you're looking after then. Find a way to better explain what you need and I'll try again.

Comment: what you did is fine but where I create the QLineF is in the mousemoveEvent. When I try and use the `angle` from the QLineF and implement it the same way the bullets display weirdly in the scene.

Comment: This won't solve your problem but I suggest you to create the line only once. Then, in the `mousemoveEvent`, just change it's angle to point toward the mouse.